# how to use Mongoid to query by a column with the name 'id'

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a collection with a column named `id`.  When I tried to do a `where` query to filter by that column name, it returns no match because mongoid is aliasing `id` to the internal `_id` field instead.   Is there a way to get around that alias without changing the column name `id` itself?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, it looks like we can disable it by using leveraging the `unalias` directive.  For example, after defining the class like below, I was able to query the collection using `id` as filter.

```
class Foobar
...
  unalias_attribute :id
  field :id, type: String
end
```